# What to do in a case of plugin ID not found?

Tags: 8

I'm fairly new to Drupal, the inside settings are quite easily to understand for me but when it gets to error fixing I'm kind getting stuck sometimes.

For a project I've installed the Open Social platform as my Drupal, which is working fine but a couple bugs and things for me to find out. I wanted a file browser as a Knowledge Base into my site so I've installed the FileBrowser module.

Now when I want to specify (open social) group rights to a file browser node, so only that group can look into this file browser, I get the following error and I cannot seem to find out where to solve it:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Component\\Plugin\\Exception\\PluginNotFoundException: Plugin ID 'group_node:dir_listing' was not found.
```

Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Did you look at the backtrace information which code is trying to load the non-existing plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is coming from a missing plugin provided by the group_node module, which if I recall ships with the Group module. Try re-downloading that module to your codebase, and clearing your cache. If that doesn't work, uninstall the group_node module.

Comment: Shamefully when I overwrite the module with a fresh downloaded one, it removes the entire option to be able to add group permissions so it seems like I'm going to have to find the problem in the code.

Comment: You probably have to enable the content type in the group settings.

Comment: Yes this has solved my issue! Thankyou for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked out :)